# Put quotes around CSV values C#

Tags: c#, csv

I have a method that converts a tab delimited text file to a CSV file and it puts quotes around fields that have a comma in it. I want to alter this method so it puts quotes around every field.

An example:

`Convert (George, Washington,was,a,president)`

to

`("George","Washington","was","a","president").`

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Below is my code:

```
public void ConvertToCSV()
    {
        //converts a tab delimited text file to a csv file
        string textFilePath = @"C:\Reports\file.txt";

        string csvFilePath = @"C:\Reports\file.csv";


        var input = File.ReadAllLines(textFilePath);
        var lines = input.Select(row => row.Split('\t'));
        lines = lines.Select(row => row.Select(field => field.EscapeCsvField(',', '"')).ToArray());
        var csv = lines.Select(row => string.Join(",", row));
        File.WriteAllLines(csvFilePath, csv.ToArray());

        System.IO.File.Delete(textFilePath);

    }

static class Extension
{
    public static String EscapeCsvField(this String source, Char delimiter, Char escapeChar)
    {
        if (source.Contains(delimiter) || source.Contains(escapeChar))
            return String.Format("{0}{1}{0}", escapeChar, source);

        return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `if (source.Contains(delimiter) || source.Contains(escapeChar))` condition?  If you want to perform this operation every time and not on certain conditions, then just remove the check for the condition and perform it every time.

Comment: Note if a data field (cell) contains a quote, you also need to escape that quote, e.g. `John "Smitty" Smith` would become `"John ""Smitty"" Smith"`

Answer (score 1):

```
    private string convertCSV(string pCSVtext)
    {
        string returnText = "";
        pCSVtext = pCSVtext.Replace(" ", "");
        string[] split = pCSVtext.Split(Convert.ToChar(","));
        for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
        {
            returnText += "\"" + split[i].ToString() + "\"";

            if(i != split.Length - 1)
            {
                returnText += ",";
            }

        }
        return returnText;
    }

string[] csvVals = new string[5] { "George", "Washington", "Was", "A", "President" };

        public string convertCSV_Array(Array pCSVvals)
        {
            string returnString = "";
            int i = 0;
            foreach(string val in pCSVvals)
            {
                returnString += "\"" + val + "\"";
                if (i != pCSVvals.Length - 1)
                {
                    returnString += ",";
                }
                i++;
            }
            return returnString;
        }
```

Given a comma delimited string such as the example, "George,Washington,was,a,president" this function would output "George","Washington","was","a","president"

Comment: Is the pCSVtext parameter expecting the name of the csv file AND its path or just the name of the file?

Comment: I want to put quotes around a whole csv file besides the header row. I feel like this method is very close to doing that.

Comment: pCSVtext would just be the output after you read the entire file to a string. okay i think i see what your doing. Instead of created a string "George,Washington,....,...," you're putting the delimited text into an array??? Wouldnt your csv variable = "George,Washington,etc..."??

Comment: Added another function, the second one will do the same thing but will take an array like ['Goerge','Washington',etc..,etc..]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just want to create a method that takes a csv file as an input and puts quotes around every field value. So if a row contains the values (George,Washington,was,...), I want it to be changed to ("George","Washington","was"...)

Comment: then you could take the csv file path as a parameter, then read all the text to an array a string or whatever you wanted, then do something similar to ^^ that to return a string with quotes around everything.

Comment: I guess i was assuming we already had a comma separated string or array to work with after reading the file.

Answer (score 0):

Plain and simple

```
var str = "George, Washington,was,a,president";

var result = "\"" + string.Join("\",\"", str.Split(',')) + "\"";
```

Result is now:

> "George","Washington","was","a","president"

`str.Split` converts separates the csv delimited strings, then you join them with `","` to put double quotes between every element, and then add double quoptes to the start and the end of the result.